# Autoloader schema evolution using foreachBatch

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Im faicing some schema evolution in my work process and I cant find the away to make it work.

Last week, I had 5 columns enabled in the ERP system and business requried to add the 6th column in the table.

My `Deltatable` was created when I had only 5 column, so Im faicing the problem in `Merge into` function that can not deal with the extra column now.

If I dont use the `foreachBatch` approach which has the `def`, containing `Merge into`, I could solve that problem with `df.writeStream.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", True)` this line of code, which autoamtically adds the column in it. I tried to use it with `foreachBatch` but it still has the problem with merging with obvious reasons.

Mycode:

```
    def update_insert(df, epochId, cdm):
    deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark,f"abfss://{container_write}@{storage_write}.dfs.core.windows.net/D365/{cdm}"+"_ao")
    deltaTable.alias('table') \
  .merge(dfUpdates.alias("newData"),
    string
  ) \
  .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    dictionary
  ) \
  .whenNotMatchedInsert(values =
    dictionary
  ) \
  .execute()



df.writeStream.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", True).foreachBatch(lambda df, epochId: update_insert(df, epochId, cdm)).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_directory).trigger(availableNow=True).start().awaitTermination()
```

Preferably I want to include that extra column in my `Deltatable` too. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mergeSchema` or `overwriteSchema` doesn't work with MERGE - instead, you need to set Spark conf property `spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled` to `true` as it's described in the `MERGE` [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-update.html#automatic-schema-evolution).

P.S. You don't need `.format("delta").option("overwriteSchema", True)` with `foreachBatch`...

Comment: in the documentation, I think first exmaple is presenting my issue (https://imgur.com/a/A2Q9PID) but documantaion says that it will not throw the error but will complete the merge opperation. Can you please explain why I get the error?

Comment: show what error you're getting

Comment: `Cannot resolve msdyn_functionallocationtype in UPDATE clause given columns table.ID, etc` indeed `msdyn_functionallocationtype` this column is in the `source_table` but not in the `target_table`

Comment: Add the code that you're trying...

Comment: code is in the question itself

Comment: any update on the above?